# MSBuild Fails to build VS2012 vb project in 64-bit format

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, build, msbuild

I had a class library vb.net project in VS2008, targeting framework v3.5. It used to build fine Release|x64 and Release|x86.
I've converted this project to VS2012, still targeting framework v3.5. It builds fine in VS IDE. But when I use MSBuild, it tells me that it can't add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` because it is already exists: `"Project already has a reference to assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic. A second reference to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll' cannot be added."`

The reference to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` is in the project if you open the Project Properties - References.

Notice - it tells me about **Framework64** reference exists, but when I open project I see **Framework** reference.

My next step is to remove this reference. I do that. Then I try to add it again. And again I receive this message: **"A reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system"**

If I try to build project without that 'explicit' reference, all the VB.Net functions are not recognized.

So, I got stuck. If I keep project "as is" I can't build it using MSBuild for x64. But if I remove reference, I can't build it anyway.
I have suspicion that it has something to do with the fact that there are 2 `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assemblies:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

Any Ideas?

Comment: are we talking about 1 solution with more projects? or just 1 project?

Comment: 1 solution, 1 project

Comment: and in the csproj file, there is only 1 reference to visualbasic.dll?? how does it look (open with notepad) . A possible solution would be to create a new VS2012 project (maybe something is wrong with conversion)

Comment: I will be comparing new vb.net proj vs existing. There could be some templates missing or incorrect. I haven't gone that way yet

Comment: The only way to know what's wrong is to open the .vbproj file in a file editor and analyze the <Reference> tags directly. Another useful way is to enable MSBuild verbose logging, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171470.aspx

Comment: Post the .vbproj contents.......(please)..  You can remove the parts that show the individual code files (.vb, .cs).

Comment: Looks like was able to dig this one out. Will put answer shortly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end it was fairly simple fix. All I had to do is remove manually from project file some xml

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic">
  <Name>Microsoft.VisualBasic</Name>
</Reference>
```

Another thing I noticed is that in the newly created **vbproj** file system references listed as following

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
</ItemGroup>
```

While in converted project the format is

```
<Reference Include="System">
  <Name>System</Name>
</Reference>
```

It is still remains a mystery, why **removing** `Microsoft.VisualBasic` **via IDE doesn't work**, even though XML is gone from vbproj. And why **removing manually works**? I went on to compare vbproj file after removal via IDE and it has done same thing as manual removal.

Comment: This solved my issues with MS Build while Building using VS never was a problem. Down-voting this answer doesn't make sense. Especially with no comments

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing similar issue, I removed reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly to make it build with msbuild.exe but now it fails to build in Visual Studio.

The projects have been upgraded from older versions, with a long history.

I compared a new VB project created with Visual Studio and it seems the solution is to add this line which isn't carried over using project upgrade:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

Comment: Possibly, you right. I removed reference via notepad and it worked for me. These projects have been building since. We use `FinalBuilder` with `MSBuild` option. With `VS` it would work. MS Build leaves little room for error in `proj` files.